Tychonoff spaces which are sequentially closed in their Stone–Čech compactifications
The sequential closure $\operatorname{sqcl}(A)$ of $A\subseteq Y$ is the set of all $x\in Y$ such that there is a sequence $x_n\in A$ with $x_n\to x$.
If the space $X$ is nice enough, then $\operatorname{sqcl}_{\beta X}(X) = X$, but this doesn't happen all the time since $\operatorname{sqcl}_{\beta X}(X) = \beta X$ when $X$ is the Tychonoff plank.
To guarantee that $\operatorname{sqcl}_{\beta X}(X) = X$, one method is as follows. Suppose that $x_n\in X$ converges to $x\in\beta X\setminus X$, and we can always assume that $x_n$ are all distinct. Let $f$ be defined by $f(x_n) = (-1)^n$. Then $f$ is a continuous bounded real-valued function on $A = \{x_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, so that if we can guarantee that $A$ is $C^\ast$-embedded in $X$, so that each such continuous bounded function can be extended to $X$, then it can also be extended to $\beta X$, and so $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$ has to exist and be equal to $f(x)$. Noting that $A$ is a closed, countable discrete subset of $X$, we have:
Proposition 1. If every closed, countable discrete subset of $X$ is $C^\ast$-embedded, then $\operatorname{sqcl}_{\beta X}(X) = X$.
In an $F$-space every countable subset is $C^\ast$-embedded, so we have:
Corollary. If $X$ can be embedded in an $F$-space, then $\text{sqcl}_{\beta X}(X) = X$
Since any $C$-embedded set is $C^\ast$-embedded, proposition 1 holds in particular when all closed, countable discrete subsets are $C$-embedded. However for this case we can phrase it in a way which doesn't mention $C^\ast$ or $C$-embedded sets:
Proposition 2. A countable discrete subset $A$ of $X$ is $C$-embedded iff for any closed set $B$ disjoint from $A$ there exist open disjoint $U$, $V$ with $A\subseteq U$, $B\subseteq V$.
Definition. Say that $X$ has property $D$ if $A, B\subseteq X$ are disjoint closed sets with $A$ countable and discrete, then $A$, $B$ can be separated by open sets. Equivalently, every closed countable discrete subset is $C$-embedded.
Corollary. If $X$ has property $D$, then $\operatorname{sqcl}_{\beta X}(X) = X$.

What's an example of a space $X$ in which every closed discrete countable subset is $C^\ast$-embedded, but $X$ doesn't have property $D$?

As answered by Anonymous in the comments, if $N\subseteq \beta\mathbb{N}\setminus \mathbb{N}$ is a copy of $\mathbb{N}$, then $X = \beta\mathbb{N}\setminus (\overline{N}\setminus N)$ has every countable subset $C^\ast$-embedded, but doesn't have property $D$.

Is there any nice characterization of spaces in which every closed discrete countable subset is $C^\ast$-embedded akin to proposition 2?

What's an example of a space for which $X$ is sequentially closed in $\beta X$, but $X$ contains a closed countable discrete subset which is not $C^\ast$-embedded?



For 1 let $N$ be a countably infinite (relatively) discrete subset of $\beta \omega \setminus \omega$, let $S = (Cl_{\beta \omega}N) \setminus N$ and let $X = \beta \omega \setminus S$.  Then the only infinite closed discrete subsets of $X$ are subsets of $N$, and they are all C$^*$-embedded, but $X$ is pseudocompact, so $N$ is not C-embedded.

@Anonymous Every countable subset of $X$ is $C^\ast$-embedded since $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is an $F$-space, but why would $X$ be pseudocompact?

It is not hard to show that if $A$ is a subset of $\beta \omega \setminus \omega$, then $\omega \cup A$ is pseudocompact if and only if $A$ is dense in $\beta \omega \setminus \omega$. To get the part that is relevant here, use the fact that if a space $X$ has a dense subset $D$ such that every infinite subset of $D$ has an accumulation point in $X$, then $X$ is pseudocompact.
